# KineticJS: no method '_addId' in anonymous function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kineticjs

So, trying to work through the KineticJS.Image tutorial, but I run into an issue.

This works:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
  var icon = new Image();    
  icon.onload = function() { 
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ 
      container: 'canvas',      
      width: 730,            
      height: 700,           
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var im = new Kinetic.Image({    
      x: -14,
      y: -13,
      image: icon,
      width: 30,
      height: 30
    });
    layer.add(im);        
    stage.add(layer);        
  };                         
  icon.src = '#{asset_path "icons.png"}';
});
```

this, which very nearly the tutorial code, does not:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'targetCanvas',
    width: 730,
    height: 700,
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var icon = new Image();    
  icon.onload = function() { 
    var im = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: icon,
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
    });
    layer.add(im);        
    stage.add(layer);        
  };                         
  icon.src = '#{asset_path "designer_icons.png"}';
});
```

It throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_addId' kinetic.js:28
  Kinetic.Container.add
  Kinetic.Stage.add
  icon.onload
```

I could have something Seriously Messed up in my environment, since this is in a serious hack job of a project (Rails w/Backbone,Require,Bootstrap and Kinetic), and I really don't know javascript or various libraries, so I'm fumbling around in the dark.

Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: The code is working with KineticJS v4.3.1 (`icon.src` just pointing to a jpg). Which version is in use? By any chance, does the code move `Kinetic.Global` somewhere else?

Comment: It's possible that some part of the hack job does this; but wouldn't that prevent the first example (the functioning one) from working?

Comment: You're correct. Could've been that the other code is in some other place of the app, but that's a theoretical thought.

Answer (score 0):

It seems stage is not initialized as a Kinetic.Node properly. Could you make it sure this exists?

```
<div id="targetCanvas"></div>
```

and also, please make it sure you are using version 4.3.1? 
I don't see 4.3.1 has that line.

If the above does not help, please post your example, so that I can take a look at it.